# Rotten Oranges LeetCode

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/rotting-oranges/

The link explains better than I can with the visuals, but basically you have to make every orange that's next to a "rotten" one (value 2) rotten as well.

I'm approaching this using a BFS. I start by making a queue for all the rotten oranges, then I pass that to my bfs function which checks if going (up/down/left/right) is possible and if it is then adds that to the queue and changes the value to show the node has already been visited.

My solution is not giving me the right answer and I'm not sure where the logical misstep is.

```
class Solution {
    public int orangesRotting(int[][] grid) {
        
        //get all 2's into a queue
        //iterate over 2 making all oranges rotten
        //iterate grid again --> anything that's not 2, return -1
        //else return count
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                if(grid[i][j] == 2) {
                    q.add("" + i + j);
                }
            }
        }

        int count = getMinutes(grid, q);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                if(grid[i][j] == 1) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    public static int getMinutes(int[][] grid, Queue<String> q) {
        
        Queue<String> rotten = new LinkedList<>();

        int count = 0;
        final int[][] SHIFTS = {
            {1,0},
            {-1,0},
            {0,1},
            {0,-1}
        };
        
        while(true) {
            while(!q.isEmpty()) {
                String s = q.remove();
                 int i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
                 int j = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.length() - 1));
                
                for(int[] points : SHIFTS) {
                    int tempI = i + points[0];
                    int tempJ = j + points[1];
                    if(isValidMove(grid, tempI, tempJ)) {
                        rotten.add("" + tempI + tempJ);
                        grid[tempI][tempJ] =  2; //it's visited
                    }
                }
            }
            if(rotten.isEmpty()) {
                return count;
            }
            count++;
            q = rotten;
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean isValidMove(int[][] grid, int i, int j) {
        if(i < 0 || i >= grid.length || j < 0 || j >= grid[i].length || grid[i][j] != 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I suggest you don't do this : `q.add("" + i + j);` How would you distinguish between `{11,2}` and `{1, 12}`, both give the same string `"112"`? Just use `q.add( new int[]{i, j} )` it shouldn't cause too much of a performance problem they are just ints. In fact its the other way around. It should be faster.
- Now coming to the main issue, your algorithm is almost correct except for the fact that you need to initialize a new Queue inside `while ( true )` because you have to start with a new queue every time you flush your current queue. The idea is you start with a queue of already rotten oranges. Rot their neighboring oranges and build a new queue consisting of the newly rotten oranges. Then repeat until your new queue of newly rotten oranges is empty. So it has to be a new queue everytime you start with already rotten oranges.

The modified `getMinutes` with the correction of the main issue is :

```
   public static int getMinutes(int[][] grid, Queue<String> q) {
        
        int count = 0;
        final int[][] SHIFTS = {
            {1,0},
            {-1,0},
            {0,1},
            {0,-1}
        };
        
        while(true) {
            Queue<String> rotten = new LinkedList<>();
            while(!q.isEmpty()) {
                String s = q.remove();
                 int i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
                 int j = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.length() - 1));
                
                for(int[] points : SHIFTS) {
                    int tempI = i + points[0];
                    int tempJ = j + points[1];
                    if(isValidMove(grid, tempI, tempJ)) {
                        rotten.add("" + tempI + tempJ);
                        grid[tempI][tempJ] =  2; //it's visited
                    }
                }
            }
            if(rotten.isEmpty()) {
                return count;
            }
            count++;
            q = rotten;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Looks pretty good!

- My guess is that your solution is missing `return 0` for if there is no `freshOranges` early.
- This is similarly a Breadth First Search algorithm, crammed into one function though for laziness purposes ( ˆ_ˆ ):

```
public class Solution {

    private static final int[][] directions = new int[][] {
        {1, 0},
        { -1, 0},
        {0, 1},
        {0, -1}
    };

    public static final int orangesRotting(
        int[][] grid
    ) {
        final int rows = grid.length;
        final int cols = rows > 0 ? grid[0].length : 0;

        if (rows == 0 || cols == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        int freshOranges = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == 2) {
                    queue.offer(new int[] {row, col});

                } else if (grid[row][col] == 1) {
                    freshOranges++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (freshOranges == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int count = 0;

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            count++;
            final int size = queue.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                final int[] cell = queue.poll();

                for (int[] direction : directions) {
                    final int row = cell[0] + direction[0];
                    final int col = cell[1] + direction[1];

                    if (
                        row < 0 ||
                        col < 0 ||
                        row >= rows ||
                        col >= cols ||
                        grid[row][col] == 0 ||
                        grid[row][col] == 2
                    ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    grid[row][col] = 2;
                    queue.offer(new int[] {row, col});
                    freshOranges--;
                }
            }
        }

        return freshOranges == 0 ? count - 1 : -1;
    }
}
```